# Some self-sufficient Chinese phrases. Help me?

Tags: pinyin

I would love to learn some more functional Chinese, especially Chinese that will allow me to become self sufficient in my own learning. I have a year of Chinese under my belt, but I am having trouble speaking to Chinese natives/students here in Shanghai. Can you translate the following phrases to me in Chinese and Pinyin?

1) How do I say this word in Chinese?

2) How do I say this phrase in Chinese?

3) What is the most standard way to say X in Chinese?

4) verb, noun, adjective. Is word X an adjective?

5) If I say something unusual or pronounce something unusually, can you do me a favor and correct me?

6) Since I am trying to learn Chinese, can you give me some useful phrases to say in Chinese everyday?

7)How do I use Chinese to say X? Can you provide me an example sentence? Can you use the word in a sentence?

Comment: １。这个词你怎么念? 
２。这句话用汉语怎么说？
３。普通话最标准的方法说X是什么？
４。名词、动词、形容词，X 这个词是形容词吗？
５。说不寻常的词句或发音异常的话，你能不能帮我一下，给我改正，好吗？
６。因为想学习中文，您能不能讲给我一些汉语词组为了日常使用。
７。用汉语X怎么说？能不能给我提供个例句呢？能不能在某句子中用这词语？ 
maybe instead of 能不能 use 请。。。好吗

Comment: S.Rhee can you add the pinyan? George Chen... I'm trying to learn how to speak Chinese.

Comment: 1.zhe ge ci ni zen me nian? 2.zhe ju hua yong han yu zen me shuo? 3. pu tong hua zui biao zhun de fang fa shuo X shi shen me? 4. ming ci, dong ci, xing rong ci, X zhe ge ci shi xing rong ci ma? 5.shuo bu xun chang de ci ju huo fa yin yi chang de hua, ni neng bu neng bang wo yi xia, gei wo gai zheng, hao ma? 6.yin wei xiang xue xi zhong wen, ning neng bu neng gei wo yi xie han yu ci zu wei le ri chang shi yong 7. yong han yu X zen me shuo? neng bu neng gei wo ti gong ge li ju ne? neng bu neng zai mou ju zi zhong yong zhe ci yu? These are the pinyin of the sentences of SRhee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Kudos to @S.Rhee and @nacho.

1) How do I say this word in Chinese?

```
这  个  词 怎  么  念? 
zhe ge ci zen me nian?
```

2) How do I say this phrase in Chinese?

```
这  话   用   汉  语  怎  么  说？ 
zhe hua yong han yu zen me shuo?
```

3) What is the most standard way to say X in Chinese?

```
用    最  标   准   的 普  通   话  怎  么  说   X？ 
yong zui biao zun de pu tong hua zen me shuo X?
```

4) verb, 动词 (dong ci)

noun, 名词 (ming ci)

adjective. 形容词 (xing rong ci)

Is word X an adjective?

```
X 是  形    容   词  吗？
X shi xing rong ci ma?
```

5) If I say something unusual or pronounce something unusually, can you do me a favor and correct me?

```
如果  我  用词    不当    或   发音   异常，    你 帮    我  改正      一下    好吗？
ruguo wo yongci budang  huo fayin yichang, ni bang  wo gaizheng  yixia  haoma?
```

6) Since I am trying to learn Chinese, can you give me some useful phrases to say in Chinese everyday?

```
因为    我   想      学习    中文，     您   讲      给   我  一些   日常用语      好吗?
yinwei  wo  xiang   xuexi  zhongwen  nin  jiang  gei  wo yixie  richangyongyu haoma?
```

7)How do I use Chinese to say X?

```
用    汉语   怎么   说   X？
yong hanyu  zenme shuo X?
```

Can you provide me an example sentence?

```
请    给  我  说   个  例句  好吗？
qing gei wo shuo ge liju haoma?
```

Can you use the word in a sentence?

```
请   用    这 词  造  个 句  好吗?
qing yong ze ci zao ge ju haoma?
```

Answer (score 1):

好像缺乏声调标记的拼音使用有限 （it seems pinyin w／o tone marks is of limited use），因为有用于这一目的的在线工具，第一评论作者好像认为把文字转变成拼音是不必要的（怎么还会有使用者不知道这事情？）（as there are online tools for that purpose, author of first comment containing suggestions apparently thought it unnecessary to use some online converter for conversion）以下就请看一眼这种转换的结果：

１ 。 zhège cí nǐ zěnme niàn

２ 。 zhè jù huà yòng hànyǚ (no umlaut) zěnme shuō ？

３ 。 pǔtōnghuà zuì biāozhǔn de fāngfǎ shuō X shì shénme ？

４ 。 míngcí 、 dòngcí 、 xíngróngcí ，zhège cí shì xíngróngcí ma ？

５ 。 shuō bù xúncháng de cíjù huò fāyīn yìcháng dehuà ， nǐ néng bùnéng bāng wǒ yīxià ， gěi wǒ gǎizhèng ， hǎo ma ？

６ 。 yīnwèi wǒ (wǒ could be omitted, since clear from context )xiǎng xuéxí zhōngwén ， nín néng bùnéng jiǎng gěi wǒ yīxiē hànyǚ (no umlaut) cízǔ wèile rìcháng shǐyòng 。

７ 。 yòng hànyǚ (no umlaut) zěnme shuō ？ néng bùnéng gěi wǒ tígōng gè lìjù ne ？ néng bùnéng zài mǒu jùzi zhōng yòng zhè cíyǔ ？

To get the changes (corrections) in answer 1, use online converter again.

Comment: No need to be snarky... sometimes the online tools don't translate it properly. With language, I just like leaving it to a person's ear instead of relying on computerized conversion.